# C program keep crashing

Tags: c, gcc, crash

well i have this simple code, it asks the user how many numbers he wants to save, then it asks for the numbers, each time the user write the number the program prints the numbers that he has written already and it sort numbers from lowest to highest.

The problem is when the user tell the program to save more than 9 numbers, the programs just stops, if the user choose to save 8 or less number it works perfect. i don't know whats happening, I'll appreciate your help

The variables and other terms are based in my language, spanish, here are some translations:

function guardaNum: saves the number in the array

function ordena: sort array's numbers

function imprime: prints the array

contador: is a counter

cant: is the amount of number the users wants to save

thanks for your help!

```
#include <stdio.h>
int guardaNum(int *pnum,int lista[],int *pcontador);
int ordena(int lista[],int *pcontador);
void imprime(int lista[],int *pcant);

int main(void)
{
  int cant, num, *pnum, lista[cant], i,contador,*pcontador ;
  printf("Ingrese la cantidad de numeros que desea agregar a la lista: \n");
  scanf("%d", &cant);

  for(i=0;i<cant;i++)
    {
      lista[i]=-99;
    }

  for(i=0;i<cant;i++)
    {
      printf("Ingrese un Numero: ");
      scanf("%d",&num);

      pnum=&num;
      contador=i;
      pcontador=&contador;

      guardaNum(pnum,lista,pcontador);
      ordena(lista,pcontador);
      imprime(lista,pcontador);
    }

}

int guardaNum(int *pnum,int lista[],int *pcontador)
{
  lista[*pcontador]=*pnum;
  return 0;

}

int ordena(int lista[], int *pcontador)
{
  int i,j, temp;

  for(j=0;j<*pcontador;j++)
    {
      for(i=0;i<*pcontador;i++)
    {

      if(lista[i]>lista[i+1])
        {
          temp=lista[i+1];
          lista[i+1]=lista[i];
          lista[i]=temp;
        }
    }
    }
}

void imprime(int lista[],int *pcontador)
{
  int i;
  for(i=0;i<=*pcontador;i++)
    {
      printf("%d\n",lista[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you used a debugger? If not, why not?

Comment: When you create the array `lista` you use an uninitialized variable `cant`. You need to first ask the quantity of numbers and then allocate enough memory to store the numbers. http://linux.die.net/man/3/malloc

Comment: No, I haven't, I don't know how to use it,I'm suppose to learn it this semester but not now

Comment: If you can't yet use a debugger, follow your program with `printf`.  Put a `printf` statement at the start and end of every function... then put more `printf`'s at any interesting point of your program.  Use them to trace through your program, inspect variables, and figure out how far it gets before it crashes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do this:

```
int main(void)
{
  int cant, num, *pnum, i,contador,*pcontador ;
  int *lista;
  printf("Ingrese la cantidad de numeros que desea agregar a la lista: \n");
  scanf("%d", &cant);
  lista = malloc(sizeof(int)*cant);
  if(!lista){
    perror("error on malloc");
    exit(1);
  }

  //continue with your code
  free(lista);
}
```

The problem with your code, is cant is uninitialized so the compiler doesn't know how much space is required for your array.

or you can do it this way:

```
scanf("%d", &cant);
int lista[cant]
//continue with your code
```

Comment: It would probably be a good idea to put a `free(lista);` before the end of `main()` in the first example, at least to encourage good habits.

Comment: @FredLarson Excellent idea. Especially for someone new like this.

Answer (score 1):

In this line:

```
int cant, num, *pnum, lista[cant], i,contador,*pcontador ;
```

You are using `cant` while it is uninitialized. You'll have to move your declaration of `lista` to be after you have input the size.

Answer (score 1):

Note that you define the array with "cant" as size *before* you actually take it as an input.
You'll either need a max possible array size (and better check your input against it), or if you know how - allocate the array dynamically